How to get a good reference for my grad school application when switching majors?
I am a final-year chemistry honors student in a South Asian country. I minored in geography. while I have gotten good grades in Chemistry (CGPA-9.23/10 up till now), I have realised my interest is more towards my minor course i.e. geography. More specifically, Urban Studies.
I am applying to Science Po, Paris Urban School for my master's course. While I believe I can convincingly argue for my switch of careers after studying chemistry for three years, due to my public policy internships in urban mobility and transport space and also being an content creator on urban design etc, I am however faced with a tough dilemma of getting two academic references for my application.
I did not build good enough relationships with my professors and most of them were also not invested in us as students enthusiastically or we had big class sizes or I only took a class with them for one semester. A few people I did have good relationship with are contractual teachers/PhD scholars (these people don't have official university emails and those who don't have official
email addresses are not allowed to give references at Sciences Po). In this case, I don't know how to approach my professors from the chemistry/geography departments. There are only 2-3 candidates in my mind but I am on the fence about them as they might straight up refuse, not properly understand my career switch or write a mediocre reference. What do you suggest I do in this case?

My own approach in seeking references was to bite the bullet and ask ... but specifically, to ask "I'm applying to XXX. Would you feel able to support me in my application".
If the answer was anything other than pretty enthusiastic (e.g., a lukewarm response like "I'm kind of busy right now but I guess I could find time" or, "Do you really think that XXX would really suit you?", etc.) then I'd move on to my next possibility. It takes courage, but it does allow one to avoid the duds.

What was your plan for if you ran out of reasonable candidates?
